# can't post data to Laravel API from flutter dio pakage Formdata

Tags: json, laravel, flutter, api, dart

i had a problem on my RESTAPI. i'm working with backend that makes the API, but i can't post data to the server. due to the error that appears on my debug console. here's the REST-API end-point source code.

`

```
class PeminjamanController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $data = Peminjaman::all();
        return response()->json(['Data User : ', PeminjamanResource::collection($data) ], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create($id)
    {
        
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request, $id)
    {
        try {
            //code...
            $data = Request()->all();
            if(  $id == 1) {
                $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
                    'dosen_id'      => 'required',
                    'matkul_id'     => 'required',
                    'spo_id'        => 'required'
                    ],[
                    'dosen_id.required'     =>'Dosen Tidak Boleh Kosong',
                    'matkul_id.required'    =>'Mata kuliah Tidak Boleh Kosong',
                    'spo_id.required'       =>'Tindakan Tidak Boleh Kosong',
                ]);
                if($validator->fails()){
                    return response()->json($validator->errors(), 
                    Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
                }
                $pinjam = new Permintaan();
                $pinjam->id                = Uuid::uuid4()->getHex(); 
                $pinjam->kd_permintaan     = $data['kd_peminjaman'];
                $pinjam->user_id           = Auth::user()->id;
                $pinjam->dosen_id          = $data['dosen_id'];
                $pinjam->matkul_id         = $data['matkul_id'];
                $pinjam->spo_id            = $data['spo_id'];
                $pinjam->tgl_minta         = Carbon::now();
                $pinjam->diserahkan        = NULL;
                $pinjam->aprovals          = "Belum";
                $pinjam->status            = "Menunggu Persetujuan";
                // $pinjam->keterangan        = NULL;
                $pinjam->save();
                foreach($request->barang_id as $key => $barang){
                    $stok = Barang::findOrFail($barang);
                    if ($request->jumlah[$key] > $stok->stok) {
                        return response('[200] - Maaf Stok Barang Melewati Batas');
                    }else{
                        DetailPinjam::create([
                            'id'                    => Uuid::uuid4()->getHex(), 
                            'permintaan_id'         => $pinjam->id,
                            'kondisi_id'            => 2,
                            'barang_id'             => $barang,
                            'jumlah'                =>$request->jumlah[$key],
                            'fix_jumlah_kembali'    =>$request->jumlah[$key],
                        ]);
                        $stokpinjam = $stok->stok - $request->jumlah[$key];
                        $stok->update([
                            'stok' => $stokpinjam,
                        ]);
                        $response = [
                            'success' => true,
                            'message' => 'Peminjaman Created',
                            'data' => $pinjam
                        ];
                        return response()->json($response, Response::HTTP_CREATED);
                    }
                }
            }elseif ($id == 2 ){
                Request()->validate([
                    'dosen_id'      => 'required',
                    'matkul_id'     => 'required',
                    'spo_id'     => 'required',
                    'tgl_kembali'   => 'required',
                    ],[
                    'dosen_id.required'     =>'Dosen Tidak Boleh Kosong',
                    'matkul_id.required'    =>'Mata kuliah Tidak Boleh Kosong',
                    'spo_id.required'       =>'Tindakan Tidak Boleh Kosong',
                    'tgl_kembali.required'  =>'Tanggal Pengembalian Tidak Boleh Kosong',
                ]);
                $data = Request()->all();
                $pinjam = new peminjaman();
                $pinjam->id                = Uuid::uuid4()->getHex(); 
                $pinjam->kd_peminjaman     = $data['kd_peminjaman'];
                $pinjam->user_id           = Auth::user()->id;
                $pinjam->dosen_id          = $data['dosen_id'];
                $pinjam->matkul_id         = $data['matkul_id'];
                $pinjam->spo_id            = $data['spo_id'];
                $pinjam->tgl_pinjam        = Carbon::now();
                $pinjam->tgl_kembali       = $data['tgl_kembali'];
                $pinjam->diserahkan        = NULL;
                $pinjam->aprovals          = "Belum";
                $pinjam->status            = "Menunggu Persetujuan";
                $pinjam->keterangan        = NULL;
                $pinjam->save();
                    foreach($request->barang_id as $key => $barang){
                        $stok = Barang::findOrFail($barang);
                        if ($request->jumlah[$key] > $stok->stok) {
                            return response('[200] - Maaf Stok Barang Melewati Batas');
                        }else{
                            DetailPinjam::create([
                                'id'            => Uuid::uuid4()->getHex(), 
                                'peminjaman_id' => $pinjam->id,
                                'barang_id'     => $barang,
                                'jumlah'        => $request->jumlah[$key]
                            ]);
                            $stokpinjam = $stok->stok - $request->jumlah[$key];
                            $stok->update([
                                'stok' => $stokpinjam,
                            ]);
                            $response = [
                                'success' => true,
                                'message' => 'Peminjaman Created',
                                'data' => $pinjam
                            ];
                            return response()->json($response, Response::HTTP_CREATED);
                        }
                    }
                } 
            
        } catch (QueryException $e) {
            //throw $th;
            return response()->json([
                'message' => "Failed" . $e->errorInfo
            ]);
        }
    }
```

`

and here the dart dio push method.

`

```
Kirim() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var token = localStorage.getString('access_token');
    try {
      var data = FormData.fromMap({
        'kd_peminjaman': kodepruduct,
        'user_id': id_pengguna,
        'dosen_id': dosendrop,
        'matkul_id': matakuliahdrop,
        'spo_id': spodrop,
        //'tgl_minta': '${tanggal.day}.${tanggal.month}.${tanggal.year}',
        'tgl_kembali':
            '${tanggalkembali.day}.${tanggalkembali.month}.${tanggalkembali.year}',
        '[barang_id][]': {
          [id]
        },
        '[jumlah[]]': {
          [jumlah]
        },
      });
      var dio = Dio();
      dio.options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
      //dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
      dio.options.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
      dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      var response = await dio
          .post('http://silk.polindra.ac.id/api/peminjaman/2', data: data);
      print(response.statusMessage);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

`

and i got response from the rest-api method like this.

[image: the error message]

i have tried to change the atribute on the FormData. on the array
`barang[]: [id], jumlah[]: [jumlah]`

to jsonEncode method

`barang[]: jsonEncode([id]), jumlah[]: jsonEncode([jumlah])`

and these too

`[barang[]]: [id]], [jumlah[]: [jumlah]]`

and the last
`barang[]: {[id]}, jumlah[]: {[jumlah]}`

all of refactoring atrribut i made, doesn't give any effect, all of  method give the same error message

can some one help me.. plz...

sorry for my bad english.. i'm not usually spoken english in my country.

Answer (score 0):

actually, the reason you get this issue is related to your API code on line 164 it suppose to string but it's returning an array. to check which parameter making an issue you can simply diedump by

```
dd($request->all());
```

and test it from the postman